# What are the standard guidelines for packaging die cuts?

Tags: mockup, packaging

Is there any online guidelines on how thin the margins should be or what the circumferences of a bottle should be in regards to label preset sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standards, as these items can have infinite variations. Talk to your printer. If a printer has not been attributed, design whatever it is you are designing with adjustments in mind. Make it so you can easily adjust artwork when you do get to talk to the actual printer.